# Pausing downloads in iTunes on Windows platform

Tags: itunes, windows

I have used many iterations of iTunes to download videos on Windows platform . However , only one iteration of iTunes the pause option did what it said , it paused the video to the point where I downloaded and restarts downloading where I left off ; something like the downthemall addon on Firefox . Now is that a feature or a bug of iTunes software on Windows platform or this is how every downloads using iTunes is supposed to work. I often have to download large files ; and restarting from the initial position is a havoc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own answer : this is a feature not a bug of Apple . There are some files that are non-resumable , and some are not .